# Run Yarn audit If package.json has changed

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Is there a way to have run yarn audit automatically before running any npm script if your package.json has been modified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a simple bash trick.

```json
{
    "scripts": {
        "audit-if-needed": "[ package.json -nt node_modules ] && yarn audit && touch node_modules",
        "my-script": "npm run audit-if-needed && ..."
    }
}
```

`-nt` means newer than

If `package.json` newer than `node_modules` run the script.

`touch node_modules` handle edge cases like your script may affect `package.json`, you don't have to use it if you don't need it.

Comment: "scripts": {
    "audit-if-needed": "[ package.json -nt node_modules ] && yarn audit",
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "npm run audit-if-needed && react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },

Comment: Here is my script and It's executed every time. I need to run that yarn audit script only if package.json is updated. What have I done wrong inside the scripts.

Comment: Can you add `&& touch node_modules` end of the `audit-if-needed` script? Probably when you make audit nothing change in node_modules so the script always runs.

Comment: I have added that, But still the same.

Comment: Can you run `[ package.json -nt node_modules ]` then run `echo $?` in project folder for debugging?